# Making JS game, where to add other objects into code

Tags: javascript, canvas, javascript-objects

I have a game concept and using w3 schools i have built the basic code for a moving game piece at the base of the canvas. I want to build a game different to the W3 games plan though. I'm not asking for help actually writing code, I'm asking for help on where in my code to add other variables/objects. Here is my current code.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
  <style>
    canvas {
      border: 5px solid #d3d3d3;
      background-color: #f1f1f1;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body onload="startGame()">
  <script>
    var myGamePiece;

    function startGame() {
      myGamePiece = new component(30, 30, "black", 350, 445);
      myGameArea.start();
    }

    var myGameArea = {
      canvas: document.createElement("canvas"),
      start: function() {
        this.canvas.width = 700;
        this.canvas.height = 480;
        this.context = this.canvas.getContext("2d");
        document.body.insertBefore(this.canvas, document.body.childNodes[0]);
        this.interval = setInterval(updateGameArea, 20);
        window.addEventListener('keydown', function(e) {
          myGameArea.key = e.keyCode;
        }) 
        window.addEventListener('keyup', function(e) {
          myGameArea.key = false;
        })
      },
      clear: function() {
        this.context.clearRect(0, 0, this.canvas.width, this.canvas.height);
      }
    }

    function component(width, height, color, x, y) {
      this.width = width;
      this.height = height;
      this.speedX = 0;
      this.speedY = 0;
      this.x = x;
      this.y = y;
      this.update = function() {
        ctx = myGameArea.context;
        ctx.fillStyle = color;
        ctx.fillRect(this.x, this.y, this.width, this.height);
      }
      this.newPos = function() {
        this.x += this.speedX;
        this.y += this.speedY;
      }
    }

    function updateGameArea() {
      myGameArea.clear();
      myGamePiece.speedX = 0;
      myGamePiece.speedY = 0;
      if (myGameArea.key && myGameArea.key == 37) {
        myGamePiece.speedX = -1;
      }
      if (myGameArea.key && myGameArea.key == 39) {
        myGamePiece.speedX = 1;
      }
      myGamePiece.newPos();
      myGamePiece.update();
    }
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Any help would be appreciated please and thank you.

For anyone interested my plan is to have different objects falling from top and as you catch them each one has a different effect on your player or the background/music.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On that code to add other objects, you will need to insert code in two places:

- **function startGame**
  This is where all the object variables are initialized
- **function updateGameArea**
  Here is where the object actually gets drawn into the canvas

---

So let's jump to an example:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
  <style>
    canvas {
      border: 5px solid #d3d3d3;
      background-color: #f1f1f1;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body onload="startGame()">
  <script>
    var myGamePiece;

    function startGame() {
      dots = []
      for (i = 0; i < 45; i++) {
        a = i*8 * Math.PI / 180
        dots.push(new component(2, 2, "red", Math.sin(a)*45 + 80, Math.cos(a)*35 + 60)) 
      }
      myGamePiece = new component(30, 30, "black", 350, 125);
      myGameArea.start();
    }

    var myGameArea = {
      canvas: document.createElement("canvas"),
      start: function() {
        this.canvas.width = 600;
        this.canvas.height = 160;
        this.context = this.canvas.getContext("2d");
        document.body.insertBefore(this.canvas, document.body.childNodes[0]);
        this.interval = setInterval(updateGameArea, 20);
        window.addEventListener('keydown', function(e) {
          myGameArea.key = e.keyCode;
        });        
        window.addEventListener('keyup', function(e) {
          myGameArea.key = false;
        });
      },
      clear: function() {
        this.context.clearRect(0, 0, this.canvas.width, this.canvas.height);
      }
    }

    function component(width, height, color, x, y) {
      this.width = width;
      this.height = height;
      this.speedX = 0;
      this.speedY = 0;
      this.x = x;
      this.y = y;
      this.update = function() {
        ctx = myGameArea.context;
        ctx.fillStyle = color;
        ctx.fillRect(this.x, this.y, this.width, this.height);
      }
      this.newPos = function() {
        this.x += this.speedX;
        this.y += this.speedY;
      }
    }

    function updateGameArea() {
      myGameArea.clear();
      myGamePiece.speedX = 0;
      myGamePiece.speedY = 0;
      if (myGameArea.key && myGameArea.key == 37) {
        myGamePiece.speedX = -1;
      }
      if (myGameArea.key && myGameArea.key == 39) {
        myGamePiece.speedX = 1;
      }
      myGamePiece.newPos();
      myGamePiece.update();
      dots.forEach(x => x.update());
    }
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

- **function startGame**
  I added `dots = []...` just a few "dot" on a elliptical pattern
- **function updateGameArea**
  And here we just call the update on the objects:
  `dots.forEach(x => x.update());`